# pass php array to jqplot chart

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jqplot

hi can one tell me how to pass php array to jqplot

this PHP:

```
Array ( [0] => 2882.89 [1] => 6913.46 ) 
Array ( [0] => 2006-01-01 [1] => 2006-01-02 )
```

to this Javascript:

```
line4=[['2006-01-01', 2882.89], ['2006-01-02', 6913.46]];
```

this is exactly my code , can someone help, thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

The line1 array in PHP should be:

```
$line1 = array( array("2010-1-1", 123) );
```

because you may have multiple data.

The following prints what you want:

```
echo "line1 = ";
echo json_encode($line1);
echo ";";
```

Comment: the line data requested by jqPlot is a JSON array ... using the method json_encode you can transform a PHP array into a json array. The square brackets in JSON represent an array ... so if you look closely you can see that jqplot is requesting an array of arrays. basically.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a long time since this question has been asked, but just in case you need a way to have more php control over your jQplot charts, you may use a php wrapper like this one https://github.com/oumsofiane1/jqplotPHPwrapper.git